# Remove unclosed tags in HTML file with Java

Tags: java, html

I need to remove the unclosed tags from a HTML file using Java. Is there a quick way to do that? Some API that automatically removes the unclosed tags when parsing the file? Or how can it be done?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with unclosed? A tag like `<div` or one that misses the closing part (e.g. the `</div>` is missing)?

Comment: One that the closing part is missing.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to process your whole file and find closing tags for every opening tag. If we can't find a closing tag, we save the line number of the opening tag so we can remove the line from the file later.

```
/*
 *  Returns a stack with the line numbers of tags that don't have a closing tag. 
 */
public static Stack<Integer> removeUnclosedTags(String filePath) {
    //Stores all HTML tags
    Stack<String> tags = new Stack<>();
    //Stores the line numbers for the tags
    Stack<Integer> lineNumbers = new Stack<>();
    //Stores the line numbers for tags without a closing one
    Stack<Integer> linesToRemove = new Stack<>();

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
        int lineNumber = 0;
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            lineNumber++;
            line = line.trim();

            //No tag on this line or a tag that gets closed right away (e.g. <br />) - just continue
            if(!line.contains("<") || line.contains("/>")) {
                line = br.readLine();
                continue;
            }
            //Check if line starts with a closing tag
            if(line.trim().startsWith("</")) {

                //If HTML tag matches the one on the top of the stack, remove it and continue
                if(line.split("</")[1].split(">")[0].split(" ")[0].equals(tags.peek())) {
                    tags.pop();
                    lineNumbers.pop();
                    line = br.readLine();

                    //If it does not match, we have an unclosed tag and store the line number
                } else {
                    System.out.println("unclosed tag at line number " + lineNumbers.peek() + ": " + tags.pop());
                    linesToRemove.push(lineNumbers.pop());
                }

                //If it is a starting tag
            } else if(line.startsWith("<")) {
                //Push it to the stack so we can compare it later
                tags.push(line.split("<")[1].split(">")[0].split(" ")[0]);
                lineNumbers.push(lineNumber);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return linesToRemove;
}
```

This method returns a stack with the line numbers that don't have a closing tag. We can then remove them like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String filePath = "/some/path/test.html";

    Stack<Integer> lines = removeUnclosedTags(filePath);

    File inputFile = new File(filePath);
    File tempFile = new File(filePath.replace(".html", "_cleaned.html"));

    BufferedReader reader;
    BufferedWriter writer;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

        String lineToRemove = "bbb";
        String currentLine;
        int lineNumber = 0;

        while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            lineNumber++;

            if(lines.empty() || lineNumber != lines.peek()) {
                writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            } else {
                lines.pop();
            }
        }
        writer.close(); 
        reader.close(); 
        //Comment this line if you want a separate file
        tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 


}
```

Comment: But doesn't this assume that each line contains only 1 tag ?

Comment: That's true, you didn't specify that.